# Why is there a gap in color at the bottom of my webpage?

Tags: html, css

I have attached my HTML along with my CSS code and a picture of the webpage. I can not figure out why there is a gap in the red background color at the bottom. Any help is much appreciated

```css
/*

Landon Byrd
Fall 2021

    Plain Red       #f60d41
    Rich Red        #f6130d
    Orioles Orange  #f64d0d
    Sunset Orange   #f6870d
    Golden Yellow   #f6c10d

*/


/* Global settings */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Papyrus
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f6130d;
  text-decoration: underline
}

.wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}


/* Nav Section */

.nav {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 25%
}


/* Main section */

.banner {
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #f6c10d;
  text-align: center;
}

.bulletPoints {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #f6870d;
  color: #f60d41;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 25px 50px 75px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpeg");
}

.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Footer section */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  color: #f6c10d;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%
}

.footer::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Copyright section */

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  color: #f6c10d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <title>Augie's Custom T-shirts</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="menu">
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <p>Shop</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <p>Events</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <p>Contact Us</p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </nav>
  <main class="wrapper">

    <div class="banner">
      <h1><span class="name">Augie's Custom T-shirts</span></h1>
      <h2>Custom T-shirts for you or your party.</h2>

      <div class="bulletPoints">

        <ul>
          <li>Birthday parties</li>
          <li>Vacation groups</li>
          <li>Bachelorette Parties</li>
          <li>Family reunions</li>
          <li>Work team rewards</li>
          <li>Business promotions</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <br/>


    </div>
    <p id="Catch">
      Do you have an event coming up, and want everyone to get in the spirit? T-shirts can bring a group together, make everyone feel connected, and let everyone know what you're celebrating.
    </p>

    <p>T-shirts can also be a great gift to someone that acknowledges their special interest or hobby.</p>

    <p>Choose from one of our unique designs, or let us put your own design on a shirt for you.</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gorilla.jpg" alt="Gorilla" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="images/pink.jpg" alt="Pink" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="images/skull.jpg" alt="Skull" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>

    <p><strong>How it works:</strong></p>

    <p>Browse our selection of unique designs, select the size and colors of the shirts you would like, and place your order. We will ship your shirts within three business days for in-stock shirts, or five days for custom size and colors.</p>

    <figure>
      <img src="images/t-shirt-colors.jpeg" alt="T-shirt colors" class="image1">
      <figcaption>Choose from are variety of t-shirt colors!</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <p>Have a design of your own? Can't find the right sentiment? Call or email us to discuss the possibilities or get some ideas for your event.</p>

    <p>Please note there will be a one time $15 charge for any custom graphics design.</p>




    <h2><em>Contact us today!</em></h2>


  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Augie's Custom T-shirts</p>
      <p>(478) 555-1212</p>
      <p>augieB@augiesTees.com</p>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>Check out are Social Media for updates!</p>
      <p>Facebook:</p>
      <p>Instagram:</p>
      <p>Twitter:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>Locations:</p>
      <br/>
      <p>100 Tanger Dr, Locust Grove, GA</p>
      <p>2954 Watson Blvd Suite 100, Warner Robins, GA</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <div class="copyright">
    <h3> @copyright: Landon Byrd</h3>
    <p>Fall 2021, All Rights Reserved</p>
  </div>

  <p>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
      <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>
  </p>

  </div>
</body>
```

Side note my verified CSS checker image is also not showing up at the very bottom of the page and the HTML checker is giving me the following error

Error: Stray end tag div.

From line 123, column 1; to line 123, column 6

[image]

Comment: At the end of your ``<body>`` you have added an ``</div>`` to much. Remove this, and the error should be gone.

Comment: You say the code is validated but it is not valid. But it is the CLEAR:BOTH on the footer that makes the space. Easily found by clicking inspect on the space and unchecking stuff one by one. I made you a snippet and formatted it and the stray div sticks out too

Comment: Why you have added to ``.footer::after`` the property ``display: table;``? If you remove this, the space also will disappear.

Comment: @Landon Byrd close the question if everything is clear please ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `h3{ margin-top: 0px; }` to your css code to remove the white line between the red divs at the bottom of the side

Answer (score 0):

> add the div with 'class=copyright' inside the footer and remove the extra `</div>` at last

Answer (score 0):

that h3 tag in your .copyright div taking the default

```
margin-block-start: 1em; 
margin-block-end: 1em;
```

you can use

```
.copyright h3{
margin-block:0;
}
```

this will remove the white space..
or you can use

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
```

this will remove the default margin and padding from the page